# Rhino, typeof and autoboxing confusion

Tags: java, javascript, rhino, autoboxing

In a server side extension for SmartfoxServer (which uses Rhino) I had a piece of Javascript similar to this:

```
response["xpos"] = properties.get("xpos");
send(JSON.stringify(response));
```

This caused errors. What happened? Because properties is a Java `Map`, when a number is put into it, it's autoboxed into a `java.lang.Double` object. Therefore, when retrieving it and storing it in `response["xpos"]`, the result is not a regular Javascript number but a `JavaObject` of type `java.lang.Double`. The `JSON.stringify` function was not meant to handle that and it crashed.

I fixed it with a hack like this:

```
response["xpos"] = 1.0 * properties.get("xpos");
send(JSON.stringify(response));
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Number(properties.get("xpos"))`, as in the following interactive console session:

```
js> x=java.lang.Double(2)
2.0
js> typeof x
object
js> x instanceof java.lang.Double
true
js> y=Number(x)
2
js> typeof y
number
```

This is how strings are typically converted in Rhino from java.lang.String to native JavaScript strings as well.